# Structure javascript and delay execution when dynamically loading scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I'm loading my javascript files using `Modernizr.load()`. Now lets say each page needs to call their own init method after everything has finished loading. But I put the loading in a template master, which is unaware of the child pages. How can the pages know when the dependencies have finished loading?

**script**

```
Page1Stuff= {
   init: function(){ alert('page 1 executed'); }
}
Page2Stuff= {
   init: function(){ alert('page 2 executed'); }
}
```

**site master template**

```
//Modernizr loads the script.
Modernizr.load([{
    load: 'jquery.js',
},
{
    load: 'script.js'
}]);
```

**page1**

```
$(function() {
    Page1Stuff.init();
});
```

**page2**

```
$(function() {
    Page2Stuff.init();
});
```

I think I see 2 problems here. If modernizr is still loading jquery, $ may not be defined. Also, `Page2Stuff` or `Page1Stuff` may not be defined.

Comment: check http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#load for 'complete' callback

Comment: @spacevillain, I'm aware of that, but how do I let my all my `pages` be aware of that?

Comment: check Modernizr object, maybe it stores loaded stuff (if doesnt, you can create simple json for this yourself). So, check it on every 'page' and if needed stuff not found ask Modernizr to load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template: Use the modernizer "complete" call back to emit a custom event to signal the loading is complete, also set a global variable saying that the scripts have been loaded.

In your page scripts: first check the global variable to see if all scripts have been loaded, if not, register a handler to listen for the custom event you emit when the loading completes.

In your template code:

```
// A simple object that calls its listeners when modernizer script loading completes.
global_scriptLoadingMonitor = (function() {
   var listeners = [];
   var isComplete = false;
   return {
      "addListener": function (listener) {
         listeners[listeners.length] = listener;
      },
      "complete": function () {
         isComplete = true;
         for (var i = listeners.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            listeners[i]();
         }
      },
      "isComplete": isComplete
   }
})();

Modernizr.load([{
    load: 'jquery.js',
},
{
    load: 'script.js'
    complete: function () {
    {
       global_scriptLoadingMonitor.complete();
    }
}]);
```

Now in your Page1 do this:

```
if (global_scriptLoadingMonitor.isComplete) {
    $(function() {
        Page1Stuff.init();
    });
} else {
    global_scriptLoadingMonitor.addListener(function() {
        $(function() {
           Page1Stuff.init();
        });
    });
}
```

And similarly for page2.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the registering a handler to listn for event?